# UITextView loses auto correct functionality when hiding QuickType Predictive suggestions bar

Tags: ios, swift

I use `textView.autocorrectionType = .no` to hide the QuickType Predictive suggestions bar, but field loses the auto correct functionality.

Is there any way to hide the suggestions bar without losing auto correct functionality?

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick, hides the bar and keeps the auto correct functionality:

```
let item = textView.inputAssistantItem
item.leadingBarButtonGroups = []
item.trailingBarButtonGroups = []
```